# Splunk: assign multiple wildwards to variables at runtime

Tags: variables, count, runtime, wildcard, splunk

I have a log4j server log with multiple lines formatted similar to the following:

```
"10.1.1.1" "AUTH-USER" "22/Jul/2013:22:42:42 -0700" "GET /source1/resources/RESOURCE/ENDPOINT/1111/start HTTP/1.1" 200 4 
"10.1.1.1" "auth2" "22/Jul/2013:22:43:03 -0700" "PUT /source1/resources/RESOURCE/ENDPOINT HTTP/1.1" 200 4
"10.40.16.254" "auth2" "22/Jul/2013:22:43:03 -0700" "PUT /source1/resources/secure/RESOURCE/v1/ENDPOINT?var1=A&var2=01-01-2013&var4=Allison HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

Where RESOURCE is a list of resources and ENDPOINT represents list of endpoints.

I would like to count the number of times a distinct pair of RESOURCE:ENDPOINT exists in the log file to know the number of times each web service has been called in a specific timeline.

I know I can perform the following search to return all of the values:

("/RevWebServices/resources/*/* HTTP/1.1" OR "/RevWebServices/resources/secure/*/*/v*/* HTTP/1.1")

But how do I extract the values in to key value pair that can be counted?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following steps will help:

1. create custom fields named "RESOURCE" and "ENDPOINT" by using field extraction. Field extraction can be done on splunk UI or in props.conf(advanced configure in transforms.conf).
2. make a temp field during search and count it using search command like "... | eval pair = RESOURCE.":".ENDPOINT | stats count by pair | ..."